# Unable to redirect to another view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, list-view, view

On my SharePoint Online site, I have a list which has 3 different calendar views. I'm trying to add a set of 3 buttons to the top of the page inside a Script Editor web part, each linking to one of the 3 views.

Currently I am trying to link to the page using an href to the url, but the page is reloading instead of directing to the new view. Is there something I need to enable to redirect these?

Comment: can you please add snippet for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be actually trying to use a `<button>` in the html breaks the hrefs. Using only an `<a>` and making it look like a button corrects the issue.